# How to export CMS Page data in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, csv, importexport, export

I have added a custom attribute to CMS Page in magento 2. Can anyone please guide me How can I Export the value of that attribute of each CMS page through Custom Module?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, But I am asking for Magento 2.

Comment: You can export table from database.

Comment: Hi, I want to add a Export Entity in Magento 2 Export Options through Custom Module.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.1, use the `PageRepository`:

```
class CustomBlock extends AbstractBlock
{
    protected $pageRepository;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Cms\Model\PageRepositoryInterface $pageRepository)
    {
        $this->pageRepository = $pageRepository;
    }

    public function getPageAttribute($attributeName, $pageId)
    {
        $page = $this->pageRepository->getById($pageId);

        return $page->getData($attributeName);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, Please check the picture in my edited question above. I want to add the separate entity for this task. Can you please help me?